# Invoke Bluemix Workflow with Node.js app

Tags: node.js, workflow, ibm-cloud

I am able to invoke my workflow with the DevOps IDE, but not with Node.js app. My Node.js app code is:

```
var buffer = new Buffer(workflowConfig.credentials.user + ":" + workflowConfig.credentials.password,"ascii");
var base64Auth = buffer.toString('base64');
var baseURL = workflowConfig.credentials.url.substr(0, workflowConfig.credentials.url.lastIndexOf('/'));
var scriptFilepath = 'helloworld';
var wfTarget = 'echo';
var APIUrl = urljoin(baseURL, 'myworkflow', scriptFilepath, '_', wfTarget);
var requestOptions = {
     headers : {
         "Authorization" : base64Auth
     }
}
console.log("APIUrl: " + APIUrl);
console.log("requestOptions: " + JSON.stringify(requestOptions));
request.get(APIUrl, requestOptions, function(error, response, body){
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send(error)
    }else{
        console.log(body);
        res.json(body);
    }
});
```

I tried running it on Bluemix and on my local env (with hard-coded VCAP_SERVICES). The response body is an HTML page with a title: "Redirect To OP"

Kindly please help

Comment: What do you mean with "I am able to invoke my workflow with the DevOps IDE, but not with Node.js app."? Please explain.

Comment: I have followed the https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/workflow/index.html#workflow tutorial: Installed and configured DevOps Services plugin for Workflow, created and deployed "Hellow world" workflow, then used the Tools > Invoke menu in DevOps IDE. All wen great. 
My next step is to invoke that workflow with Node.js app. I could find only one example, and followed it. But cannot see the "Hello world" response.